# How to explode two array fields to multiple columns in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was referring to [How to explode an array into multiple columns in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49499263/how-to-explode-an-array-into-multiple-columns-in-spark) for a similar need.

I am able to use that code for a single array field dataframe, however, when I have a multiple array fields dataframe, I'm not able to convert both to multiple columns.

For example,

**dataframe1**

```
+--------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|                 f1 |f2                                |f3                                |
+--------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|12                  |                              null|                              null|
|13                  |                              null|                              null|
|14                  |                              null|                              null|
|15                  |                              null|                              null|
|16                  |                              null|                              null|
|17                  |                [[Hi, 256, Hello]]|        [[a, b], [a, b, c],[a, b]]|
|18                  |                              null|                              null|
|19                  |                              null|                              null|
+--------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

I want to convert it to below dataframe:

**dataframe2**

```
+--------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|                 f1 |f2_0                              |f3_0                              |f3_1                              |
+--------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|12                  |                              null|                              null|                              null|
|13                  |                              null|                              null|                              null|
|14                  |                              null|                              null|                              null|
|15                  |                              null|                              null|                              null|
|16                  |                              null|                              null|                              null|
|17                  |                  [Hi, 256, Hello]|                            [a, b]|                         [a, b, c]|
|18                  |                              null|                              null|                              null|
|19                  |                              null|                              null|                              null|
+--------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

I tried with the following code:

```
val dataframe2 = dataframe1.select(
  col("f1") +: (0 until 2).map(i => col("f2")(i).alias(s"f2_$i")): _* +: (0 until 2).map(i => col("f3")(i).alias(s"f3_$i")): _*
)
```

But it is throwing an error saying it is expecting a ")" after the first "_*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+:` is used in Scala to add a single element to a list. It can't be used to concatenate two lists together. Instead, you can use `++` as follows:

```
val cols = Seq(col("f1")) 
  ++ (0 until 1).map(i => col("f2")(i).alias(s"f2_$i")) 
  ++ (0 until 2).map(i => col("f3")(i).alias(s"f3_$i"))

val dataframe2 = dataframe1.select(cols: _*)
```

Note that to use this approach, you need to know the number of elements of the lists in advance. Above, I changed 2 to 1 for the `f2` column.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I have one syntax doubt. What does the last _* expression mean in my code? I didn't understand that part from the reference link.

Comment: @user3243499: Glad to help. I think the answers here explain it better than I could: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala

Answer (score 0):

Shaido answer is already correct and this answer is only an enhancement to that. Here I just added to find the max length of the columns dynamically.

If the column `f2` and `f3` is already array, there corresponding max array sizes are computed as below.

```
val s1 = df.select(max(size(df("f2")))).first().getInt(0)
val s2 = df.select(max(size(df("f3")))).first().getInt(0)
```

Else if the column should be splitted based on the delimiter and further divide into columns, first computing the size as below.

```
val s1 = df.select(max(size(split(df("f2"), ",")))).first().getInt(0)
val s2 = df.select(max(size(split(df("f3"), ",")))).first().getInt(0)
```

And then we can use the `s1`, `s2` in the map function in the Shaido answer as 
`(0 until s1).map( .....`