# How can I split an array of structs into columns in Spark?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, schema

I have an column containing an array of phone numbers represented as structs, and need to put them into three columns by a "`type`" attribute `(phone1, phone2, fax)`.

Here are two sample values of the column.

```
[{"number":"000-000-0000","type":"Phone1"},{"number":"000-000-0001","type":"Phone2"},{"number":"000-000-0002","type":"Fax"}]
[{"number":"000-000-1000","type":"Phone1"},{"number":"000-000-1001","typeCode":"Fax"},{"number":"000-000-1002","type":"Phone2"}]
```

I want to split each into three columns, one for each type.
I want something like this:

```
   Phone1           Phone2           Fax
000-000-0000     000-000-0001     000-000-0002
000-000-1000     000-000-1002     000-000-1001
```

This answer shows how to put each element of the array into its own column. 
[How to explode an array into multiple columns in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49499263/how-to-explode-an-array-into-multiple-columns-in-spark)

This gets me halfway there, but I can't rely on the order of items in the array. If I do this I'll get something like this, where the Phone2 and Fax values in the second column are out of place.

```
   Phone1           Phone2           Fax
000-000-0000     000-000-0001     000-000-0002
000-000-1000     000-000-1001     000-000-1002
```

How can I split the single column value into three columns, using the type value? An array can have 0-3 numbers, but will never have more than one number of each type.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way which involves flattening the phone/fax#s via `explode`, followed by pivoting on the `typeCode`, as shown in the following example:

```
case class Contact(number: String, typeCode: String)

val df = Seq(
  (1, Seq(Contact("111-22-3333", "Phone1"), Contact("111-44-5555", "Phone2"), Contact("111-66-7070", "Fax"))),
  (2, Seq(Contact("222-33-4444", "Phone1"), Contact("222-55-6060", "Fax"), Contact("111-77-8888", "Phone2")))
).toDF("user_id", "contacts")

df.
  withColumn("contact", explode($"contacts")).
  groupBy($"user_id").pivot($"contact.typeCode").agg(first($"contact.number")).
  show(false)
// +-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
// |user_id|Fax        |Phone1     |Phone2     |
// +-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
// |1      |111-66-7070|111-22-3333|111-44-5555|
// |2      |222-55-6060|222-33-4444|111-77-8888|
// +-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: What if the DF contains other columns, which you want to keep? One can add them into the `groupBy` clause, but that doesn't work with unorderable types like a MapType.. The only solution I can think of involves joining those columns back to the pivoted DF.. all fairly expensive operations..